# How can I run a .desktop file which starts a script file, but hides the terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I wrote a .desktop file which should start an .sh file. It works good but opens a terminal with the logs of the started application. When I close the terminal also the application gets closed. The application is the webstorm IDE. Here is my .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=webstorm
Terminal=false
Icon=/pah/to/webstorm-icon.svg
Exec=/path/to/webstorm.sh
```

Is there a way to hide the terminal and only start the application? Please note that I already set the parameter Terminal to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh oh. Sorry. Seems, that some Props (like `Terminal=false`) just takes effekt after reboot. I should pay more attention to "It Crowd".